# running linux on virtual machines for experimentation

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtualization

I usually use virtualbox to run linux as guest on my windows. I now want to run linux as guest on a linux machine. I'm using virtualization for experimentation on networks. I was told that virtualbox isn't the best to be used in this case. 
Is there a better vm i can use ?

Comment: Who told you not to use VirtualBox? It Works.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Virtualbox in Linux and run any linux based OS. I myself use Ubuntu and run Centos in Virtualbox, there isn't any issue.

Comment: is it possible to set up a whole virtual network including routers ?

Comment: Internet works fine inside Virtualbox but don't know the use of routers for Virtual Machine. Please elaborate.

Comment: i need to virtualize a newtwork(independent of internet), for e.g i'll run 3 virtual machine one of which will be a router and then send packets from one vm such that the packets reaching the second vm will go through the virtual router

Comment: @lukasirides It should work. Give it a try.

Comment: i was reading some docs online...u're right it should work